# Aligining the Menus and submenus into the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.mkey, 0 child_menu_mkey, UPPER(a.menu_name) parent_menu, '' child_menu 
FROM wms_menu_hdr a,
     wms_menu_hdr b 
WHERE a.mkey = b.parent_mkey 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT b.mkey, b.mkey child_menu_mkey, '' parent_menu, b.menu_name child_menu 
FROM wms_menu_hdr a,
     wms_menu_hdr b 
WHERE a.mkey = b.parent_mkey 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

which displays me results as

I am using `SQL-server-2005`

Comment: UNION removes duplicate rows, so there's no need to also do SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: which one do you want as a result? the one with parent menu? or child menu?

Comment: @jarlh: even after removing, i still get the duplicate `mkey`

Comment: @coder, I know. Just wanted to point out that DISTINCT makes no difference when UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My old answer was to another question, but we cleared this up, so try this one:

```
SELECT parent_key, child_key, parent_menu, child_menu
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT a.mkey AS mkey, 0 child_menu_mkey, UPPER(a.menu_name) parent_menu, '' child_menu, mkey AS parent_key 
        FROM wms_menu_hdr a
        WHERE a.mkey IN (SELECT parent_mkey FROM wms_menu_hdr)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT b.mkey, b.mkey child_menu_mkey, '' parent_menu, b.menu_name child_menu, a.mkey AS parent_key
        FROM wms_menu_hdr a,
             wms_menu_hdr b 
        WHERE a.mkey = b.parent_mkey)
ORDER BY parent_key, child_menu_key;
```

Comment: sorry was in a meeting, getting error as `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.`

Comment: marmarta: any suggestions on this error ? kindly suggest.

Comment: hi, if you could make the changes as suggested, than I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005, where there are no window functions, you need some kind of subquery, like:

```
WITH t AS
(
        SELECT DISTINCT a.mkey, 0 child_menu_mkey, UPPER(a.menu_name) parent_menu, '' child_menu 
        FROM wms_menu_hdr a,
             wms_menu_hdr b 
        WHERE a.mkey = b.parent_mkey 
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT b.mkey, b.mkey child_menu_mkey, '' parent_menu, b.menu_name child_menu 
        FROM wms_menu_hdr a,
             wms_menu_hdr b 
        WHERE a.mkey = b.parent_mkey) 
SELECT t.mkey, t.child_menu_mkey, t.parent_menu, t.child_menu
FROM t JOIN (SELECT child_menu_mkey, min(mkey) AS min_mkey 
         FROM t 
         GROUP BY child_menu_mkey) AS g 
        ON t.child_menu_mkey = g.child_menu_mkey AND t.mkey = g.min_mkey;
```

Comment: getting error as `'first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: a, right, sorry, you said it's sql server 2005. Gimme me a minute, I'll refactor it with the older syntax.

Comment: i am only able to see one `parent_menu` i.e `Admin`. not others like                `PUT AWAY PROCESS` etc

Comment: marmarta, anything for getting more `parent_menu` as with the above query, I am getting only one `Parent_menu` ?

Comment: ok, then I don't understand what are the duplicates you try to eliminate. Which rows should be selected? I thought you meant eliminating duplicate child_menu_mkey, but obviously not (in the answer you want there are duplicates), so - what is the goal?

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake, I dont want to delete the `mkey` rather than display the result as I have shown in the `UPDATE` of my question

Comment: Alright, but I don't understand why these are the rows you selected. What do they mean? Why these rows? What logic governs this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97275/discussion-between-coder-and-marmarta).